# Is there a way to force log entries on svn check in?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

There is a desire in one of my teams to force user's to provide a log entry on check-in.

I think the only available approach is to create a custom repository hook to reject a check-in.  Is this correct ?  Any existing examples or commentary on the approach ?

Comment: You can use the management approach of punishing anyone who does a checkin without comment.  You don't have to be a member of CSI to find who is guilty... `svn log` :-)

Comment: @Amardeep this is normally one of my preferred approaches.  Personally, I'm less of a fan of log entries because I wouldn't trust anything in them.  When looking for problems, I prefer reviewing the diffs.  The question is coming from a team I don't directly manage, so I'm encouraging them find their own way with a bit of advice.  ;-)  thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pre-commit hook is the only way that I find to reject empty commit logs.

See this:

http://code.google.com/p/subversion-pre-commit-hook/

Comment: +1. Also, you can get very sophisticated in the commit hook. We audit ours to ensure that there is a valid change request or defect ID in the comment (there's a particular format that we use, so it can be parsed).  If you don't include a valid change request or defect ID, you can't check in. period.

Answer (score 3):

From the [TortoiseSVN docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-minlogmsgsize.html):

> TortoiseSVN uses properties to control some of its features. 
>   One of those properties is the `tsvn:logminsize` property.
>
> If you set that property on a folder, then TortoiseSVN will disable the OK
>   button in all commit dialogs until the user has entered a log message with at
>   least the length specified in the property.

Comment: This is fairly helpful when taking the management approach as it gets away from the individual with the "oops, I forgot" syndrome.

Answer (score 1):

I think the commit script hook is the way to go, but that will not prevent users to write "asdfasdf" in the comment field just to check-in stuff.

but that's another subject.

Max.